# Mongodb return unexpected files according to the given regex asking for parenthesis

Tags: javascript, regex, mongodb

On below you can see a list of values of the field I am interested to request:

```
r3-vitré[matinée]
toulouse
r3-rouen-mauquenchy[matinée]
r2-pau
saf-r3-vaal
ger-düsseldorf
r12-argentan
aus-tabcorppark(melton)
aus-tabcorppark(menangle)
gb-chelmsford(grande-bretagne)
```

I used the well know website https://regex101.com/ to test some regex.
I did try with `\([a-z-.]+\)`, and as expected it returns only last three results. As you can see in the "Match information" corner.
But in my mongodb request: `db.collection.find({"field":{$regex:"\([a-z-.]+\)"}})` it returns even `toulouse` and so on. This is not limited to the values where there is truly parenthesis.

Where am I wrong?

Versions:

```
~$ mongod --version
db version v4.0.9
git version: fc525e2d9b0e4bceff5c2201457e564362909765
OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.1.0g  2 Nov 2017
allocator: tcmalloc
modules: none
build environment:
   distmod: ubuntu1804
   distarch: x86_64
  target_arch: x86_64
```

Comment: You need a regex literal, `$regex:/\([a-z.-]+\)/`, or double the backslashes.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew great, in my case `{$regex:"\\([a-z.-]+\\)"}` works. Thank you.